# how to create custom popup?

Tags: php, javascript, popup

how to make a custom popup. most importantly without the close button

here's a little bit of the code

```
if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($email) || empty($phone_no) ||empty($curr_state) || empty($curr_loc)){</br>
echo("<script> alert('Fill in details')</script>");
}
else{
if(strlen($password)>40){
    echo("<script> alert('Password is too long')</script>");
}
else{ 
$insert = 'INSERT INTO user(username , password , email , phone_number , curr_state , curr_loc) VALUES ( "'.$username.'", "'.$password.'" , "'.$email.'" , "'.$phone_no.'" , "'.$curr_state.'" , "'.$curr_loc.'" )';
mysql_query($insert);
echo("<script> alert('Registration Successful')</script>");
```

Comment: Your insert query is prone to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/944681)..

Comment: Why not use a jquery plugin to create a popup ?

Comment: You could use a jquery plugin like Alok said or use jquery to popup your popup HTML element

Comment: @Alok don't you think it would be allot easier to do it yourself?

Comment: Just think how it works... One layer covers another. So now just make it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into a css/html template system like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html). they offer really nice samples of how to do pop ups and alerts.

also, i'd suggest validating your form data first in javascript before sending the form to your server for further validation (like unique username or email address).

this way, in your javascript you can start calling templates like bootstrap. the following code won't compile i'm just giving you an idea

example: html

```
<form name="registration">
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="validateform()">register!</input>
</form>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

example: js

```
function validateform() {
    var name = document.form.registration.username;
    //validate name...
    // if name is valid then submit with $.ajax
    // else call bootstrap modal like $('#myModal').modal('show')
}
```

Comment: yeah but you don't need to validate if username length is greater than 2 characters, or email address includes "@", or repeat password matches on the server side. this is why i wrote further validation on the server side in my original answer :)

Comment: Javascript validation can be useful, but you just have to do validation on server side.

Comment: come again....
me very noob in programming
i'm only 2 months old in programming so u need to be a little bit more detail